# What does it mean that `attr_accessor` / `attr_reader` create an instance variable?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, attr-accessor

The documentation for [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) explicitly says that it creates an instance variable:

> [...] creating an instance variable (`@name`) and a corresponding access method [...]

As does the documentation for [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):

> Creates instance variables and corresponding methods [...]

I understand the second part, i.e. that `attr_accessor` and `attr_reader` create methods, but I don't get the first part.

What does it mean that they "create an instance variable"?

Comment: It is important to remember that http://ruby-doc.org/ is not maintained by the Ruby core team. It sometimes speculates that some things should be stable, while no such claim is officially made. Other times it speculates things about the implementation that are incorrect.

Comment: @ndn: all these years I thought that ruby-doc is auto-generated from source code comments. Are you saying that isn't so? :mindblown:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, [you appear to be correct](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/dc6d7cc58e78903e8309ff94c9e7112d661646ee/object.c#L2062-L2065), (while it is still not maintained by the core team). So the comment in the code is just wrong...

Comment: @ndn: it is wrong _technically_, if we want to be pedantic. Maybe the author of the comments meant to be more general. "creates instance variable" as in "an instance variable, matching this accessor name, will be a thing at some point in the object lifecycle". Or maybe I'm playing devil's advocate too much here :)

Comment: @ndn: it appears that we have Dave Thomas to blame for that comment, written 14 years ago. We can ask him on twitter or something :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug/misleading wording in documentation. The `attr_reader`/`attr_accessor` themselves don't create any variables. How can they? They work outside of class instance lifecycle. And even read access don't make the instance variables come to life. Only write access creates them.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.instance_variables # => []
foo.bar # try read ivar
foo.instance_variables # => [], nope, not yet
foo.bar = 2 # write ivar
foo.instance_variables # => [:@bar], there it is
```

Comment: Technically, accessors could for example add a step to the initialization process that sets said instance variables to `nil`. But as you demonstrate, that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

> The documentation for [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) explicitly says that it creates an instance variable:
>
> > [...] creating an instance variable (`@name`) and a corresponding access method [...]
>
> As does the documentation for [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):
>
> > Creates instance variables and corresponding methods [...]
>
> I understand the second part, i.e. that `attr_accessor` and `attr_reader` create methods, but I don't get the first part.
>
> What does it mean that they "create an instance variable"?

The documentation is at least misleading if not plain wrong. They create methods, nothing more. On most Ruby implementations, the implementation is in the host language (e.g. C for YARV, Java for JRuby) with special privileged access to the internals of the implementation, but actually, you can write them in plain Ruby:

```
class Module
  def attr_reader(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_method(attr) do
        instance_variable_get(:"@{attr}")
      end
    end
  end

  def attr_writer(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_method(:"{attr}=") do |val|
        instance_variable_set(:"@{attr}", val)
      end
    end
  end

  def attr_accessor(*attrs)
    attr_reader(*attrs)
    attr_writer(*attrs)
  end
end
```

Comment: YARV's implementation also performs a check: if the attribute name is not a valid instance variable name, a `NameError` is being raised. e.g: `attr_reader '1'` results in ``invalid attribute name `1'``. Maybe the documentation is referring to that check.